# jQuery tooltip plugin - fade is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jquery-tooltip

I am using the [jQuery tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip). I have a template with a few HTML controls, which I load when I click on a button (after page load). When I bind the template with data, I call the `BindTooltip` method that binds the tooltips to the above set of controls.

```
$("#btnAddCity").tooltip({
    bodyHandler: function() {
        return 'Add city here';
    },
    delay: 100
});
```

The problem comes when I try to empty data in my template and rebind it with different data. I am getting the JavaScript error:

> fade is null or not an object

Below is the code from `tooltip.js` and `settings(current)` is undefined when I try to empty and rebind my template data. Am I missing anything here?

```
// Delete timeout and show helper
function show() {
    tID = null;
    if ((!IE || !$.fn.bgiframe) && settings(current).fade) {
        if (helper.parent.is(":animated"))
            helper.parent.stop().show().fadeTo(settings(current).fade, current.tOpacity);
        else
            helper.parent.is(':visible') ? helper.parent.fadeTo(settings(current).fade, current.tOpacity) : helper.parent.fadeIn(settings(current).fade);
    } else {
        helper.parent.show();
    }
    update();
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you're "re–binding" the tooltip method?

Comment: I just call this code:$("#btnAddCity").tooltip({
        bodyHandler: function() {
            return 'Add city here';
        },
        delay: 100
    });